# TIMESTAMPDIFF, multiple row results on new column

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a student database which has a date of enrolment column. I need to run a query on sql that lets look up this date and today's date, and display the difference in yy Years mm Months.

I'm using TIMESTAMPDIFF to work out the difference between these dates but can only produce one value, how can I adapt it to work it out for the entire row? i need to create a new column with this data.

This is the query:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, CURDATE(), (SELECT time_enrolled FROM student) )
AS newDate
```

If I add a "where" statement at the end i get the specified id for example:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, CURDATE(), (SELECT time_enrolled FROM student WHERE f_id = 4) )
AS newDate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a subquery.  Your original query should be:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, CURDATE(), time_enrolled) AS newDate
FROM student;
```

The subquery will generate an error if it returns more than one row in a scalar context -- such as returning a value in the `select` statement.

You can add an appropriate `where` clause to this query if you like.

EDIT:

To get years and months, use modulo arithmetic:

```
SELECT floor(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, CURDATE(), time_enrolled) / 12) as years,
       mod(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, CURDATE(), time_enrolled), 12) as months
FROM student;
```

Comment: Also, how can I insert this data into a new column as a permanent column and any ideas on how to change the results to years, for example one of the values i get is 78, how can I format it so that is displays as 6 Years 6 Months, thank you very much for your help.